# Does a Force-sensitive person broadcast Force presence signal while asleep?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-force

Can the Force presence of a sleeping Force-sensitive person be detected?

As I understand it, Force presence has to do with midi-chlorian presence in the fabrics of the Force realm. So, the Force presence of a sleeping Force-sensitive should be detected.

But, an another thing confused me: doing something with the Force needs active consciousness. For example, if a Jedi is lifting a stone & she loses consciousness, the stone will drop. Similarly, Force Stealth ([which Palpatine was using to hide his Force presence](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/13850/931)) shouldn't work without consciousness. Am I right? If yes, then it must be true that a sleeping Force-sensitive doesn't broadcast force presence signal.

Which one is true?

Comment: I imagine that Palpatine would have been exposed quickly if he could only be hidden from the Jedi half of the time.

Comment: I don't think *everything* requires consciousness. Using telekinesis as the base and then overgeneralizing it to all force powers is I think in error. For example, a Jedi hibernation trance doesn't really require consciousness in the same way telekinesis would. I would imagine that since the Force in many ways is like a "sixth sense", there would be aspects of it that are active while sleeping as well.

Comment: @rsegal That's true. See last sentence of 3rd paragraph...

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Since even stones and X-wings are present in the force, I'd say no, there is no need to be conscious.

Comment: Doing *some* things require consciousness. In Episode 2, Anakin has Force Visions and sees Shmi being tortured. In C-Canon, Luke's children have Force Visions as well.

Comment: @DVK - because the statements about the Force requiring conciousness were errantly based and showed "no research effort" to show they were not true

Comment: @SSumner - Some Force based actions DO require consciousness.

Comment: @DVK - yes, but the characterization of doing *anything* with the Force requiring conciousness was what I was referring to

Answer (score 2):

Yes I believe that you can detect a Force sensitive even while asleep... there are a few ways to detect them... One of them being the Midi-chlorian count...

Let's say you have a sleeping person and you know that there was a Jedi / Sith presence in the area... If you really wanted to you could go around testing people's blood for the presence of Midi-chlorians..

One person actually commented on my answer to the question...

[How do the Jedi find Force-sensitives?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48340/how-do-the-jedi-find-force-sensitives/48343#48343)

> In one of the books (Thrawn?) they discover a device which can read
>   force sensitivity from a person. Maybe that device can just remotely
>   detect Midi-chlorians. –  Jack B Nimble 2 days ago

I don't think the user of the Force can hide the presence of the Midi-Chlorians in their blood so this is a way to detect Force sensitives even while asleep...

There is also this..

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force-sensitive

> In Leia's quarters in the abandoned Emperor Palpatine's Imperial
>   Palace on Coruscant, Luke and his twin sister Leia Organa Solo were
>   doing some tests on the inner defenses of her brain. Luke was using
>   the Force to access certain areas of the brain; as he accessed an area
>   in the very back of the brain, he was rebuffed. They confirmed this to
>   be a natural reflex of the Force-sensitive.

The above mentioned quote is from post Star Wars movies.  So even if a Force sensitive user is asleep, if somebody tries to use the Force to access certain areas of a person's brain and get rebuffed then they are a Force user.. I believe since it states it is a natural reflex even while asleep this reflex should still be active.

Comment: I am talking about detection based on force presence signal.

Comment: You don't need active consciousness if there's a portion of the brain that is a natural reflex, the part where if a person with force is trying to access it is rebuffed.